# Google Docs spreadsheet form / permissions

Tags: webforms, google-apps, google-forms

I have a Google Doc spreadsheet, which I created a native Form for.  I copied the form code, and integrated it into my own page [here](http://www.md4lm.com/test/index.php).

This form was working until I gave the website owner permission to view the spreadsheet.

Since then, when we hit submit, it takes us to the native form page, and does not insert form data into the spreadsheet. (You're welcome to test the form.)

Should providing viewing permissions to the spreadsheet break my own version of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set permissions via docs.google.com? If so then no it should not have changed anything. I got all the way through the form to "Attending
Your response has been recorded." Is this what you are getting as well or do you have a backend error?

If it is not a backend error and I was able to get somewhere you couldt I would suggest clearing your browser chache and possibly resetting your router as sometimes they hold a cache of older versions of a website.

Comment: The problem is that my own graphical web page used to do the submission of data to the spreadsheet.  Now, there is an intermediary form which appears after clicking submit, which was the original native form I took the code from.  I don't want this intermediary form showing.

Answer (score 0):

Did the current form of yours manage to work this before? I mean. It is shown that in the native form the questions are text boxes. While in your GUI form, it had radio buttons and check boxes, since you are calling the native post back url?

Comment: Yes, it managed to work once for me.  The native form just uses fields to receive information.  These fields can just as easily be sent information from radio buttons and check boxes.